# Flutter InAppPurchase's queryProductDetails always return 0 products

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am having a hard time fetching my Subscriptions. `queryProductDetails` always returns zero product unless I use the test product id `android.test.purchased`. Please help me find what am I missing. My app is in production (older version without in-app purchase) with in-app purchase in internal testing. I have also added my email as Licences Tester in play console and both of my subscriptions are active.

My Code to Fetch Products:

```
final Set<String> productIDs = {"invest.physical","general.physician"};
ProductDetailsResponse result = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(productIDs);
print("total found ---> ${result.productDetails.length}");
print(result.error);
print("total not found ---> ${result.notFoundIDs.length}");
print(await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable());
```

it gives 0 found and 2  not found with isAvailable true.

My Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.invest_near_me">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
   <application
        android:label="Invest Near Me"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version"
           android:value="5.0.0" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Dependency Version:

```
in_app_purchase: ^3.0.8
```